# How to run a JavaScript function as soon as possible?

Tags: javascript

As of now I'm using "window.onload" method, but it waits until the page is fully loaded and only then executes the function. It results in a blinking behavior.

How can one overcome this problem?

```js
function simplefunction() {
$(".span1").text("I'm loaded!");
}

window.onload = simplefunction;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="span1">I'm not loaded yet!</span>
```

Comment: Use `DOMContentLoaded` when you need to access any element in the DOM but before external resources are loaded. If you don't' then just invoke the function directly after it's declared.

Comment: Avoid assigning to `onload` or other event-properties like that - instead use `.addEventListener`. You need to use `addEventListener` to subscribe to `DOMContentLoaded` anyway as it isn't exposed via an event-property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fastest:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="span1">I'm not loaded yet!</span>
<script>
$(".span1").text("I'm loaded!");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function simplefunction() {
$(".span1").text("I'm loaded!");
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(e){

  simplefunction();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="span1">I'm not loaded yet!</span>
```

Comment: That is the same as the very first comment to the question 18 minutes ago